# U-boot sections specifications

Tags: u-boot

I am currently trying to wrap my head around how u-boot is organized and I was wondering if you could help clarify some of the sections in an config -> include/configs/vexpress_aemv8a.h

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE            0x80000000 
/* from what I understand, this is where the code thinks it will be placed in memory */

#define CONFIG_SYS_INIT_SP_ADDR         (CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_BASE + 0x7fff0)
/* I do not understand where this comes into play */

#define CPU_RELEASE_ADDR                (CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_BASE + 0x7fff0)
/* I do not understand where this comes into play */

#define V2M_BASE                        0x80000000
/* I do not understand where this comes into play */

/* Miscellaneous configurable options */
#define CONFIG_SYS_LOAD_ADDR            (V2M_BASE + 0x10000000)
/* I do not understand where this comes into play */
```

I would much appreciate if you could detail where and how these memory zones are used.

Comment: I would try to search the source files to get a grasp where these defines are used.

Comment: Yes, I have already dug down into the sources but I was hoping some quick and dirty advice so I can solve an issue at hand. I will eventually have to get acquainted with the rest of U-boot but for the moment I am pressed by time.

Comment: I don't use U-boot for my current work. But I would consider to use it as it is and use the bunch of environment variables that are provided for customization. Especially when you are pressed by time.

Comment: @harper I didn't even get so far as a prompt so I could use enviroment variables. I am debugging u-boot, I do not have a working copy in order to tinker with and see what works and what doesn't :D.